# Javascript hasOwnProperty for chain (nested) of properites?

Tags: javascript

I expect the following chain of properties (nested objects) `error.response.data.errorCode` on object `error`. How can I check that `errorCode` really exists? Of course - I can write the following code:

```
if (error.hasOwnPropert('response') {
    if (error.repsonse.hasOwnProperty('data') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, I can also write function, that parses property name (`error.response.data.errorCode`) and that recursively check the existence of expected property but maybe there is already built-in and optimized function for this?

Comment: That will throw an error. Spelling matters in programming

Comment: you could check with `var obj = error; if (['response', 'data', 'errorCode'].every(k => obj.hasOwnProperty(k) && (obj = obj[k], true))) {`

Comment: No, there's no builtin for this, you have to write your own (or use one of the many libs providing one)